# Symfony 3 get form via ajax, send parameters to form model and execute custom query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have controller where route is defined

```
/**
 * @Route("/", options={"expose"=true}, name="AppBundle_Frontend_index")
 * @Template
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed(null, SearchCarsType::class, new SearchCars());
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $formView = $form->createView();
    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        $cars = $this->get('app.car_repository')->findByForm($form->getData());
        $response['success'] = true;
        return new JsonResponse( $response );
    } else {
        $cars = $this->get('app.car_repository')->findAll();
    }
    return [
        'cars' => $cars,
        'form' => $formView
    ];
}
```

I have src/From/Model where I get form data

```
class SearchCars
{
public $capacityFrom;
public $capacityTo;
public $orderBy;
}
```

and I have ajax

```
$("#searchCars").submit(function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var url =  Routing.generate('AppBundle_Frontend_index');
    var formSerialize = $(this).serialize();
    $.post(url, formSerialize, function (response)
    {
        console.log(response);
    }, 'JSON');
});
```

When I press submit button my form is posted and I can read data that are posted via ajax. Problem is that I can't get it to my form model so they can be passed to my repository for custom search with query builder. I can get data in controller with $request->get('data_name') but I can't send it to model.
Any suggestions ?